# Can we reopen this question about saving money?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, closed-questions

I asked a [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/134453/how-can-i-avoid-the-inter-bank-exchange-rate-when-transferring-a-large-sum-from) about finding ways to save money on an international transfer which seems to be within the question guidelines of this forum according to the on-topic page:

> Personal Finance and Money Stack Exchange is for people who want to be
> financially literate, find ways to save money, minimize taxes, invest
> wisely, plan for retirement, etc. Also for financially-savvy amateurs,
> DIY-investors & personal finance pros.

I believe it was closed because I said I welcomed recommendations for businesses. My question was not targeting recommendations and I removed that sentence.

EDIT: I see that I've received some downvotes but no explanation. Would anyone have a suggestion to improve the quality of the question?

Comment: In case you can't see the votes to reopen your modified question, there are three so far.